# How do I treat the first item in a group created by groupby separately?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples `(name, path, ref)` which is sorted and I am using `itertools.groupby` to group them by `ref`.

I am trying to do something different for the first item of each group.

The code goes like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

docs = [('foo', '.', 'ref2'), ('bar', '.', 'ref2'), ('baz', '.', 'ref1')]
docs = sorted(docs, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0]))
for k, g in groupby(documents, itemgetter(2)):
    grouped_docs = list(g)
    print(grouped_docs[0][0], 'came first.')
    for doc in grouped_docs[1:]:
        print(doc[0], 'came after')
```

This works but I have to convert `g` to a list and then slice it.

Is there a way to get the first item of `g` and then iterate through the rest of the generator without using a list?

Something like:

```
for k, g in groupby(docs, itemgetter(2)):
    first_item = <*magic*>(g)
    print(first_item[0], 'came first.')
    for doc in g:
        print(doc[0], 'came after')
```

Comment: You mean like `first_item = next(g)` ?

Comment: As a note - since you're importing `itemgetter` anyway for use in the `groupby` you may as well use it in the sort. You can replace `key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0])` with `key=itemgetter(2, 0)`.

Comment: @JonClements Sure, in the real code I have `x[0].lower()`, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just an iterator, use `next` to get the next value, and then the first item is consumed (So it won't show up in the for loop.)

```
for k, g in groupby(documents, itemgetter(2)):
    first_item = next(g)
    print(first_item[0], 'came first.')
    for doc in g:
        print(doc[0], 'came after')
```

Comment: Gosh, that's what I tried first but for some reason I had another bug that made me think it was more complicated than that! Thanks for saving my time!

Answer (score 1):

g is an iterator, and python iterator by default has an `.__next__()` method. This can be viewed using help(g).

Anyway, the code will be like:

```
for k, g in groupby(documents, itemgetter(2)):
    first_item = next(g)  ###  = g.__next__()  will do the same job.
    print(first_item[0], 'came first.')
    for doc in g:
        print(doc[0], 'came after')
```

General guide on iterator/generator: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html